# Eclipse Plugin Development: Debbuging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I want to write a debugger for my eclipse plugin and I've been searching online for quite a while, is there any good tutorials or maybe some code explanation about how to develop that kind of thing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'write a debugger for my plugin'?  This is far too broad and vague to answer as it stands.

Comment: @greg-449 I mean to write a debug ui that will work with an outside application where I'll be able to put breakpoints, step into, step over, etc.

Comment: That is a huge amount of work, far too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @greg-449 So can you give me a clue maybe how should I start this?

Comment: I think this article will be helpful: [How to write an Eclipse debugger](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Debugger/how-to.html)